# Fisher transformation for pearson allows building a different confidence interval than for spearman?

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, spearman-rho, fisher-transform

I'm confused by the wikipedia articles for Fisher transformation for [spearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance) and [pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation). It looks like for Pearson, the confidence interval is built around $\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho})$ where $\rho$ is the true correlation coefficient, and for Spearman it is built around $\rho=0$.

Is that the case? why? Isn't Spearman simply applying the Pearson correlation on ranks? Can both cases be specified in the same manner, e.g. building a confidence interval around the true Spearman and the true Pearson?

Related to [How to calculate a confidence interval for Spearman's rank correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18887/how-to-calculate-a-confidence-interval-for-spearmans-rank-correlation)