# How to calculate the margin of error for a spearman correlation with a 95% CI

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, spearman-rho

I am completely new to any form of stats and I'm trying to calculate the margin of error for a spearman correlation, however I couldn't find anything that would help me.

Id want it for a 95% confidence interval and if you have any suggestions for software that could make this easier I would be very thankful.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate it for Pearson correlation?

Comment: I am familiar with the Fisher Z transformation yes

Comment: Perhaps see [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18887/how-to-calculate-a-confidence-interval-for-spearmans-rank-correlation). which may be helpful. Also Google `Spearman correlation confidence interval R` for a procedure in a library of R that gives a CI.