# How to statistically compare two rank correlations?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, spearman-rho, ranks

Lets suppose I have three random variables: $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.

I can use the [Spearman Rank Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient?oldformat=true) to measure the degree of monotonic relation between any two of them. However what if I want to compare the monotonic relation between $X$ and $Y$ to that of $X$ and $Z$ (i.e. answer the question: do $X$ and $Y$ have a stronger monotonic relation than $X$ and $Z$). Is there a principled way to go about this?

Comment: This older question and answers might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18887/how-to-calculate-a-confidence-interval-for-spearmans-rank-correlation

Comment: That (using Fisher transformation) would give a good start on identifying differences in two independent correlations, at least asymptotically; the potential issue here is the common X variable in the comparison, though if there's an argument that the transformed correlations should be asymptotically bivariate normal (that would seem to be likely at first glance) maybe there's a test to be had that way. Outside that, I'm not confident that there's going to be an exchangeable quantity here, so maybe a permutation test wouldn't work. In large samples, perhaps some form of bootstrap could be used